# How to get values of array into global variable

Tags: javascript

How do I get values of array into global variable?

```
var p = new Array();
var all_Y_values = 0;
for (var r = 0; r < embeddedCells.length; r++)
{
    p[r] = embeddedCells[r].attributes.position.y;
    all_Y_values = p[r], all_Y_values; 
    console.log("all y values: " + all_Y_values); //prints all values
}
console.log("all y values: " + all_Y_values); //prints only last value
```

Right now inside the loop I am able to print all values inside loop but when I print the same outside loop its printing only last value.

Comment: `all_Y_values = p[r], all_Y_values;` is parsed as `(all_Y_values = p[r]), all_Y_values;`, which is equivalent to `all_Y_values = p[r]; all_Y_values;` which is equivalent to `all_Y_values = p[r];`.

Comment: if you want all the values into all_Y_values, make it a string and concatenate them

Comment: Or just use `p`, which already is an array containing all of your values.

Comment: @Vamsi Its printing "undefined" when I make `all_Y_values as string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your collection of values is already inside "p":

```
var p = new Array();
var all_Y_values = 0;
for (var r = 0; r < embeddedCells.length; r++) {
  p[r] = embeddedCells[r].attributes.position.y; 
  console.log("current y value: " + p[r]); //prints current value
}
console.log("all y values: " + p.join(','));
```

p.s. : p and all_Y_values are not global, but local variables. In javascript only, function create a new context. Loops are not.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to print the values now. I want to covert these values to array. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

This should print all y values at the end (ps : new version using forEach)

```
var p = new Array();
embeddedCells.forEach (function (e, i) {
    p[i] = e.attributes.position.y;
    console.log("current y value: " + p[i]); //prints current value
});
console.log("all y values: " + p.join(", "));
```

Hope it works